# Customer Group Code Limited to 32 Chars - Why?

Tags: customer-group

The name/code for customer groups is limited to 32 characters. A client has groups with names that are longer.

Is there any reason not to increase the length?

Comment: I wonder if it's somehow related to MySQL4. Can't imagine what; first thought was a generated column name derived from two group code + something else. There are a lot of length = 32 columns in the setup scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainly because the field `customer_group_code` from the table `customer_group` is a varchar with the length of 32.
It has been like this since the beginning. See `mysql4-install-0.7.0.php` in the customer module.
Now...why is that column only 32 chars long?...that's an other philosophical question.

Comment: The field length is exactly what led me to the conclusion that it is limited..

I searched for a reason, but could not find one. This is mostly a sanity check.

Comment: Oh. I thought it was this constant `Mage_Customer_Model_Group::GROUP_CODE_MAX_LENGTH`. I based my answer on that assumption. Now my answer seams stupid. :)

Comment: I'd rather have stupid answers than crickets. At this point in the project I am going to change the length and see what blows up.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason I can think of is that if not documented, an old co-worker would have to look to stack exchange when adapting some legacy code only to find this question posed and in turn answering why this legacy code broke.

Comment: lol! I knew it was a bad idea to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Some DBMS have a limitation in column name length and Magento should respect that limit because its DB abstraction layer virtually allows it to run on DBMS other than MySQL.

I say "virtually" because, for example, it seems that Oracle 10g max column name length is limited to 30 characters: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/756558/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-table-name-in-oracle).

MySQL max column name length extends to 64 instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6868302/maximum-length-of-a-table-name-in-mysql.

Kind regards

Comment: This is interesting, but I don't think that's the answer. The column had that length even in version 1.0 when Mangento supported only mysql.